# Why does initialization of array of pairs still need double braces in C++14?

Tags: c++, c++14, initializer-list

With the C++14 standard, the initialization of an `std::array` can go with single braces (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

This, however, does not work for an `std::array` of `std::pair`.

Why do these work:

```
std::pair<int, int> p { 1, 2 };
std::array<int, 3> a {1, 2, 3};
```

But this does *not* work:

```
std::array<std::pair<int, int>, 3> b {{1, 11}, {2, 22}, {3, 33}};
```

While this does work again?

```
std::array<std::pair<int, int>, 3> b {{{1, 11}, {2, 22}, {3, 33}}};
```

Also, for completion, the initialization of a good old array does work with single braces

```
std::pair<int, int> c[3] {{1, 11}, {2, 22}, {3, 33}};
```

Comment: Heads-up to everyone wondering this: if the fact that brace-initialization carries ambiguities isn't clear to you, *you need to stop using brace initialization*, because chances are that even your previous code that *does* compile is being similarly misinterpreted and you just don't know that it's buggy. From which follows a useful lesson: new features are something to stay *away* from until you understand them, not something to embrace until you get burned by them...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This appears to be a parsing ambuguity somewhat similar to the famous  [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). I suspect what's going on is that:

If you write

```
std::array<std::pair<int, int>, 3> b {{1, 11}, {2, 22}, {3, 33}};
```

the compiler has two ways to interpret the syntax:

1. You perform a full-brace initialization (meaning the outermost brace refers to the aggregate initialization of the `std::array`, while the first innermost one initializes the internal member representation of `std::array` which is a real C-Array). This will fail to compile, as `std::pair<int, int>` subsequently cannot be initialized by `1` (all braces are used up). clang will give a compiler error indicating exactly that:

   ```
   error: no viable conversion from 'int' to 'std::pair<int, int>'
    std::array<std::pair<int, int>, 3> a{{1, 11}, {2, 22}, {3, 33}};
                                             ^
   ```

   Note also this problem is resolved if there is no internal member aggregate to be initialized, i.e.

   ```
   std::pair<int, int> b[3] = {{1, 11}, {2, 22}, {3, 33}};
   ```

   will compile just fine as aggregate initialization.
2. (The way you meant it.) You perform a brace-elided initialization, the innermost braces therefore are for aggregate-initialization of the individual pairs, while the braces for the internal array representations are elided. Note that even if there wasn't this ambiguity, as correctly pointed out in [rustyx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50599168/7703564), the rules of brace elision do not apply as `std::pair` is no aggregate type so the program would still be ill-formed.

The compiler will prefer option 1. By providing the extra braces, you perform the full-brace initialization and lift any syntactical ambiguity.

Comment: But how is it formalized that compilers always chose 1? I guess compilers don't "prefer" as that leaves room for ambiguity in implementation.

Comment: @Chiel As this question was not tagged `language-lawyer` I didn't bother (yet) to dig into the depths of the standard. I guess the answer won't be explicitely written there, it's rather a consequence on how the grammar of C++ is defined.

Comment: Do you think it is worth this tag?

Comment: Why does `std::array<int, 3> a {1, 2, 3};` work? If option 1 is preferred, then `1` is used to initialize the C-array, which is ill-formed.

Comment: @xskxzr Your example clearly cannot be interpreted as a full-brace aggregate initialization, as you only provided a single pair of braces. The ambiguity lies on the meaning on the inner braces, which aren't existent here. So in this context, this can only be a brace-elided initialization.

Answer (score 15):

The C++14 [brace elision rule](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.init.aggr#11) applies only to subaggregate initialization.

So for example something like this works:

```
std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3> a{1, 11, 2, 22, 3, 33};
```

Here an aggregate of aggregates can be list-initialized without extra braces.

But `std::pair` is not an [aggregate](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.init.aggr#1) (it has constructors), so the rule does not apply.

Which means that without the brace elision rule, `std::array`, itself being an aggregate with an array inside, needs an extra set of braces in order to be *list-initialized*. Remember that the class template `array` is implemented as:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N> 
struct array {
  T elems[N];
};
```

To *list-initialize* it without the brace elision rule, you need an extra set of braces to get to the `elems` member.

Comment: Good theory, but [why](https://ideone.com/WjFaeS) doesn't it work for an aggregate trivial `mypair<int, int>` without any constructors either? I guess, the syntax ambiguity still stays, even though clang now gives a more reasonable error message indicating missing braces.

Comment: Correct, the brace elision rule creates ambiguity, and is best useful as an all-or-nothing approach, i.e. you either elide all the braces (except the outermost ones of course), or you elide nothing.

Comment: OP does not ask whether the innermost braces can be elided. It asks whether the middle braces can be elided.

Comment: And I explain why no braces can be elided.

Answer (score 8):

Without the double braces, the statement is simply ambiguous. Consider the following code:

```
    std::array<std::pair<int, int>, 1> a = {{ {1, 2} }};
    std::array<int, 2> b = { {1, 2} };
```

Without double braces in the first definition, the compiler will treat `{ {1,2} }` as a *scalar initialization list* for `array<int, 2>`.
You need to declare an explicit *nested braced-init-list* in order for the compiler to recognize that the inner list is also *aggregate-initialized* (vs. scalar initialized), such that it can construct an array of `std::pair`.

Comment: "(due to brace elision)." Note that, as rustyx nicely pointed out in his answer, that there should be no brace elision in this case. It's just ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

In theory `std::array` should be initialized with aggregate initialization. So actually this:

```
std::array<int, 3> a {1, 2, 3};
```

is a syntactic sugar for this:

```
std::array<int, 3> a {{1, 2, 3}};
```

As You see, in the first one it seems I initialize array with values, but it is really aggregate initialization with braced init-list. This is clear as a day in the second situation. So that's for starters.

Ok so why does not this work?

```
std::array<std::pair<int, int>, 3> b {{1, 11}, {2, 22}, {3, 33}};
```

Well, simply put - the compiler can't distinguish what type of syntax You are using to initialize the array. `{1, 11}` can be interpreted both as initializer list and use the first version or it can be interpreted as a pair and go with the second version.

This code:

```
std::array<std::pair<int, int>, 3> b {{{1, 11}, {2, 22}, {3, 33}}};.
```

removes ambiguity.

Source: 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Comment: There should be no `initializer_list`s involved afaics.

Comment: Braced-init-list is not the same as `std::initializer_list`. Braced-init-list is a form of initializer; `std::initializer_list` is a class. Aggregates does not have a user-provided constructor. It is impossible to involve a `std::initializer_list` in anyway.

Answer (score -2):

I'm going to guess here.
The initializer list for `std::array<T,n>` should be a list of `T` (or trivially constructable to `T`). So you could do

```
std::array<std::pair<int,int>,3> b { std::pair{1,11}, std::pair{2,22}, std::pair{3,33} };
```

but that is tediously verbose. In order to get the conversion to `std::pair<int,int>` you want, you need to provide an initializer list, so

```
std::array<std::pair<int,int>,3> b {
    { // element 1
      { // initialize from:
        { 1,11 } // std::initializer_list
       }
     },
  ...
};
```

I can't defend this further, but note that `std::vector<T, Allocator>::vector( std::initializer_list<T>, const Allocator& alloc=Allocator())` is defined but `std::array<T,n>::array( std::initializer_list<T> )` is not. Neither is `std::pair<U,T>::pair( std::initializer_list<??> )` defined.

Comment: Aggregate initialization does not involve any `std::initializer_list`. A braced-init-list is not a `std::initializer_list` even though the compiler converts the former to the later in some situations.

Comment: <hang-head-in-shame>that will teach me to guess on SO </hang-head-in-shame>

Comment: @jwm Guessing is okay as long as your guess is reasonable. But in `language-lawyer`-tagges questions, standards surely are higher.

Comment: @Jodocus not defending the answer, but in no version of this question was it tagged with language-lawyer. (language-lawyer was mentioned in a comment on a different answer though)

Comment: @Mr.Mindor Sounded like I indicated that, but I didn't mean to. Was just meant as a general statement.