# I have some questions about the way to assign values to the std::array

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I'm learning C++ on codesdope.com and I have read a document on another website, learncpp.com. But these two websites have different ways to assign values ​​to the array.

```
//codesdope.com

std::array<int,5> n  {{1,2,3,4,5}};
```

```
//learncpp.com

std::array<int,5> n = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Which way is more accurate? Which way should I choose? What is the difference between them?

Comment: I think first one is optimized, and is considered as `arr[1][1]` which is the same as single array, thus it is optimized by compiler to just `arr`.

Comment: @WeaktoEnumaElish The answer to that question is about C++11, but the situation has changed in C++14 so this shouldn't be marked as duplicate.

Comment: @PaulSanders probably the DV do not know that depends on the c++ version (I didn't know too before reading interjay, but I do not DV, I UV), we are all waiting for interjay answer now ^^

Comment: @interjay That's a good point. I hadn't considered that. It looks like this question can still [happen in C++14 too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50598248/why-does-initialization-of-array-of-pairs-still-need-double-braces-in-c14), just in a different way. It looks like this would make a good canonical question to combine the different pieces of information on how this works.

Comment: sorry i'm missing "=" in my code, i've just edited

Comment: I don't think this question is opinion based. Aggregate initialization has always been a complicated topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Double-braces required in C++11 prior to the CWG 1270 (not needed in C++11 after the revision and in C++14 and beyond):

```
// construction uses aggregate initialization
std::array<int, 5> a{ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} }; // double-braces required in C++11 prior to the CWG 1270 revision
std::array<int, 5> a{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // not needed in C++11 after the revision and in C++14 and beyond
std::array<int, 5> a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};  // never required after =
```

[std::array reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

Comment: you may add the revision number too (c++ CWG 1270 revision), because such a requirement is not in c++11 anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Both versions have the same assembly code:

```
    std::array<int,5> n {{1,2,3,4,5}};

    mov     rcx, qword ptr [.L__const.main.n]
    mov     qword ptr [rbp - 24], rcx
    mov     rcx, qword ptr [.L__const.main.n+8]
    mov     qword ptr [rbp - 16], rcx
    mov     edx, dword ptr [.L__const.main.n+16]
    mov     dword ptr [rbp - 8], edx
```

the second style:

```
    std::array<int,5> n2 {1,2,3,4,5};

    mov     rcx, qword ptr [.L__const.main.n2]
    mov     qword ptr [rbp - 24], rcx
    mov     rcx, qword ptr [.L__const.main.n2+8]
    mov     qword ptr [rbp - 16], rcx
    mov     edx, dword ptr [.L__const.main.n2+16]
    mov     dword ptr [rbp - 8], edx
```

meaning they both have the same performance.
The second is better, because it is more readable.

Comment: @QuốcCường they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

`std::array` is an aggregate type, A type is aggregate type if it doesn't have private or protected direct non-static data members, user-provided constructor, virtual function and virtual, private or protected base classes, for example,

```
struct S
{
  int arr[5];
};
```

So It can be initialize like `S s = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4};` here element of `s.arr` get copy initialize by braced-init-list. Similarly `std::array` is also an aggregate type and all following different syntaxes,

```
std::array< int, 5> arr{ { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}}; // double-braces required in C++11 prior to the CWG

std::array< int, 5> arr{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
std::array< int, 5> arr = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
```

shall trigger aggregate initialization and there is no difference in them. Even it can be initialize in following way as well

```
std::array< int, 5> arr = {};
std::array< int, 5> arr = { 0, 1, 2};
```

In case of empty list `{}` elements of `arr` shall be value initialized and having following value `[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` and in case of list having less elements `{ 0, 1, 2}` then first 3 elements of `arr` shall be copy initialized from braced-init-list and remaining elements shall be value initialize and final value would be `[ 0, 1, 2, 0, 0]`

Please check more details at [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)